# Can I debug a C dll with a C# app within Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, c++, c, dll, visual-studio-2017

I know it can be done with C++, but can't get it to work with C.

We have a stand-alone hardware device using an ARM controller with firmware written in C. In order to speed testing  we decided to create a software simulation of the device which consists of a C++ dll using the actual device C firmware as source code and a C# GUI interface.

The dll was created using a C++ template with the Configuration->C/C++->Advanced->Compile As set equal to 'Compile as C Code (/TC)'. The GUI and dll work fine, but I would like to debug the C dll source code but can't get mixed mode debugging to work. Is the C compiler not compatible with mixed mode debugging?

Comment: There is a pdb file that contains the symbols needed for debugging.  Without the pdb file you are only able to debug in assembly code.  I normally debug by creating a log file and output info to the debug when the symbol file is not available.

Comment: In addition to the missing of debugging information, Odds are the dll is optimized. Optimization almost always makes code look like it went through a blender. It's not impossible to use a debugger with optimized code, but it can be very hard to make sense of the flow.

Comment: Make sure your C dll is built in Debug with a .PDB file, then set the VS project properties for the dll (Debugging) to start an external program (your simulator). Then breakpoints in the C dll will be hit. Launch the dll project in the debugger, not the simulator.